# How to fetch a file using objectid in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a file named myFile.png in image database. Is there a way to fetch it from the database using it's objectId rather than its filename? I currently use, 
    `mongofiles -db image -u db -p pwd get myFile.png`
to get my image file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB - mongofiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797976/mongodb-mongofiles)

Comment: You can "thank" me by up-voting the answer when you get some more reputation :)