# How to upload more than one document into MongoDB using one single file of JavaScript, Node JS, Shell Script or mongofile CLI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a few HTML files in a directory, I want to send/upload them to MongoDB using either pure JavaScript, NodeJs, shell script or mongofile CLI. Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If these are small files, you can convert it to `Base 64` & store in Mongo DB using either `mongo-shell` or `NodeJS`.

If you are using Node JS APIs, you can use `multer` to upload files to server & then convert it to **Base 64 Buffer** before saving in DB.

If these files are large (more specifically larger than 16 MB) then you can use `mongofiles` tools for the same.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution with **mongofiles put**, here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797976/mongodb-mongofiles) to answer by @hoogw